# Why does the C++ standard still allow uninitialized primitive variables?

Tags: design, c++, memory, languages, language-specifications

If reading uninitialized memory is undefined behavior anyway, why has the C++ standard not been changed so that objects of primitive type (int, unsigned, float, double, bool, char) get default-initialized to 0? Wouldn't this prevent an entire class of typical beginner mistakes? From my understanding, it should be possible to define any new behavior in this way that has previously been undefined.

Is there a specific reason, such as a possible ABI break, that prevents this change?

Comment: Seems like a good compiler ought to have an option to auto-initialize values it can't prove to be set-before-access.  It's not like the performance-improvement gained from skipping auto-initialization in ambiguous cases is free -- it comes at the cost of security, maintainability, and reliability.  Somewhere, somehow, some compiler has to ensure correctness -- whether that's the compiler in someone's head or in a computer.

Comment: @Nat You mean in a debug-mode to something like 0xDEADBEEF? That happens. But initializing to something potentially useful like zero would run the risk of creating a much slower dialect. And it would be much harder to diagnose the error.

Comment: @Deduplicator: I'd be curious about how much of it a performance-hit it'd be.  Presumably it'd have no effect when variables are provably set, nor when a programmer annotates a guarantee -- the only performance hit would be on variables that neither the compiler nor programmer could assert safe.  Though in that niche, it'd seem like an issue of which'd be worse: having a variable that isn't known to be set-before-access vs. having that variable initialized.  And in cases where that trade-off would be bad for performance-critical reasons, a flag/annotation could suppress it.

Comment: @Nat As I elaborated later, it doesn't really help as much as you might think if it is reliably set to *something*, as long as you cannot guarantee that *that something* is what it should be. And no, no heuristic or ad-hoc-rule will reliably give you a useful starting-value. [DWIM greets.](http://www.catb.org/~esr/jargon/html/D/DWIM.html) Anyway, JVM and CIL also cater to partially trusted bytecode, thus the cost of enforced initialization, per default zero, is just the cost of doing business. Doubly so due to their ctor-virtualcall-semantics, which are troublesome enough.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The guiding principle there is still "You don't pay for what you don't use".  It has not been changed to "Let's *try to* play it safe, and hope the compiler fixes our performance".

It's only "*try to* play it safe", as zero/null while a valid value for all fundamental types, is not always sensible. Put another way, not all values are always allowed. Actually, debug-modes which initialize to something distinctly non-zero to help debug errors the compiler fails to diagnose are quite common. `0xDEADBEEF` for data and `OXDEADC0DE` for code are long-standing favorites for their distinctiveness in a hex-viewer, `0xAA` is not uncommon for a single-byte pattern.

Proving that a useless just-in-case zero-initialization is actually useless is an impossible task in the general case, especially in the face of partial information (what can that function return, given what I know about the arguments) and limited time (yes, AOT compiler have much more than JIT compiler, but combinatorial explosion is really astoundingly fast).

As a matter of *Quality of Implementation*, compilers are free to warn about use-before-assignment, if they can be reasonably sure it happens, so the programmer can fix their code. And most do, if you politely ask for that help.

Answer (score 2):

> [...] so that objects of primitive type (int, unsigned, float, double, bool, char) get default-initialized to 0? Wouldn't this prevent an entire class of typical beginner mistakes?

I don’t think so. Usually the actual mistake is that the programmer either assumed the variable would be initialized to something useful after the declaration, or simply forgot to init it right there.

In many cases forcing zero initialization would only mask the problem. `0` is a valid value for all of the fundamental types but that doesn’t imply it’s useful and semantically valid for the use case in question. Consider:

```
/* Just for demonstration! This is BAD code! */

int result;  // uninitialized

// The function is supposed to initialize `result` to >=1 using an out parameter.
// But it’s buggy and doesn’t touch `result` at all.
fill_result(result);

// `result` is read here in some way.
```

Currently reading `result` at the end is undefined behaviour. Forced zero init wouldn’t improve the situation because the variable still does not contain a semantically valid value. It’s expected to hold a value *greater than 0*, after all. The error is just masked and likely to lead to problems later in the execution of the program. That’s very similar to undefined behaviour.

I can’t speak for the C++ committee, of course. And I cannot look into the mind of the C++ community as a whole. But I guess this is at least one important part of the reason why forced zero init isn’t considered as a change to the language – “you don’t pay for what you don’t use” being another important part.

Imo a better, although ultimately just as hopeless, idea would be to disallow uninitialized variables altogether. That *would* solve the problem, but would also be a backwards incompatible change to a commonly used feature. A proposal that’s guaranteed to break a vast amount of existing code is highly unlikely to make it into the standard.

What’s left is static and dynamic code analysis to detect such bugs.

Answer (score 2):

> If reading uninitialized memory is undefined behavior anyway, why has the C++ standard not been changed so that objects of primitive type (int, unsigned, float, double, bool, char) get default-initialized to 0?

I see two important reasons

- compatiblity with past specifications of C++ (e.g. [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf)) and past implementations (compilers like [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/))
- performance: if the compiler generated an implicit zero-ing of every automatic variable, more machine code would have to be generated, and this hurts performance

Notice that in 2021 the GCC compiler is [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html) (you can improve it) and accepts [plugins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html): **you are allowed to extend GCC with your plugin providing the behavior you want** (and you might use the [Bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/) static source code analyzer, above GCC, as a starting point. Contact me by email to `basile.starynkevitch@cea.fr`)

And **the [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/) compiler is [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source), so you are allowed to improve it**.

If you use GCC, [invoke it](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) with all warnings and debug info, e.g. `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` and learn to use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger.

Once you have a proof of concept implementation implementing your desired behavior, you could propose an improvement to the future C++ standard. I am sure the C++ standard committee will be happy to discuss that item with you. They would ask experimentation and benchmarks.

They are corner cases (e.g. [PRNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) and its seeding, or implementation of [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASLR) inside some operating system kernel?) where a non-initialized random value might perhaps desired.

Comment: Using indeterminate values as part of seeding is a known bug that haunted some PRNG implementations, I think even some OS kernels. Not that it would generally add all that much entropy if allowed, even if it is hard to predict without decompiling a specific image to try to find out where the value originated.

Answer (score -1):

It’s allowed because C and C++ are old. And enforcing such a rule is difficult. But C++ doesn’t allow *the use* of undefined variables, it’s undefined behaviour. If you look at a modern language like Swift, that *enforces* the rule that a variable may not be used unless it is initialised in such a way that the compiler can determine that it is initialised. It *allows* variables not being initialised.

Forcing initialisation has the huge disadvantage that you can’t force initialisation to a reasonable value. And blindly initialising everything means the compiler cannot tell you when there was no *meaningful* initialisation. For example: int yearOfBirth = 0; Now it’s “initialised” but the value is nonsense.